# writing numpy codes in cython with unknown dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Suppose I have a Cython code, with functions that calculates a rolling moving average and returns an array of the same size as the input (the function adds `nan` for the initial part, but this is not important for the problem at hand).

I have written three Cython functions (given below):

(a) `sma_vec` to handle `numpy` arrays of 1-dimension

(b) `sma_mat` to handle `numpy` arrays of 2-dimension

(c) a third `sma` to return values from either `sma_vec` or `sma_mat` depending upon the size. (My motivation is to eventually replace the `cpdef` before `sma_vec` or `sma_mat` to `cdef` so that the Python code only sees the `sma` function)

**Function 1 - handles `numpy` arrays of 1-dimension**

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar
ctypedef double dtype_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef sma_vec(ar[dtype_t, ndim=1] x, int m):
    cdef int n
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef ar[dtype_t, ndim=1] y
    if m == 1:
        return x.copy()
    else:
        y = np.zeros_like(x) * np.nan
        n = x.shape[0]
        if n < m:
            return y
        else:
            for i in range(m-1, n):
                for j in range(i-m+1, i+1):
                    if j == i-m+1:
                        y[i] = x[j]
                    else:
                        y[i] += x[j]
                y[i] /= float(m)
            return y
```

**Function 2 - handles `numpy` arrays of 2-dimension (calls Function 1 on each row of `ndarray`)**

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef sma_mat(ar[dtype_t, ndim=2] x, int m):
    cdef int n
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef ar[dtype_t, ndim=2] y
    if m == 1:
        return x.copy()
    else:
        y = np.zeros_like(x) * np.nan
        n = x.shape[0]
        if n < m:
            return y
        else:
            for i in range(0, x.shape[0]):
                y[i] = sma_vec(x[i], m)
            return y
```

**Function 3-calls Function 1 or Function 2 depending upon dimension**

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef sma(ar[dtype_t] x, int m):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return sma_vec(x, m)
    elif x.ndim == 2:
        return sma_mat(x, m)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Cannot handle more than two dimensions')
```

**Test Code**

```
import numpy as np
import common.movavg as mv

x1 = np.array([1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 5.3, 2.3])
y1 = mv.sma_vec(x1, 3)
y1a = mv.sma(x1, 3)
```

`y1` and `y1a` both return `array([nan, nan, 1.233333, 2.666667, 2.966667])` correctly

```
x2 = np.array([[1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 5.3, 2.3], [4.2, 1.3, 2.3, 5.7, -1.3]])
y2 = mv.sma_mat(x2, 2)
```

`y2` returns correctly

```
array([[  nan,  1.2 ,  1.35,  3.3 ,  3.8 ],
       [  nan,  2.75,  1.8 ,  4.  ,  2.2 ]])
```

But when I try:

```
y2a = mv.sma(x2, 2)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-dc092e343714>", line 3, in <module>
    y2a = mv.sma(x2, 2)
  File "movavg.pyx", line 54, in movavg.sma (stat\movavg.c:2206)
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

In the `sma` function, the issue seems to be that `ar[dtype_t] x` (i.e. `np.ndarray[double] x`) automatically assumes `x.ndim` should have a dimension of `1`.

How can I re-write the `sma` function so that it can accept `np.ndarray` with unknown dimensions ?

Comment: Looks like a copy-paste error: you're calling the vector after your check for `x.ndim == 2`: `elif x.ndim == 2: return sma_vec(x, m)`. Change that to `return sma_mat(x, m)` and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I changed it, but the code surprisingly gives the same error

Comment: Just to check, but you did recompile it after making the change?

Comment: yes, I did. a few times actually. did it run on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

found the answer.

From this link: [numpy_tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing), "... “ndim” keyword-only argument, if not provided then one-dimensional is assumed ..."

The solution is to convert the Function 3 into:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef sma(ar x, int m):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return sma_vec(x, m)
    elif x.ndim == 2:
        return sma_mat(x, m)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Cannot handle more than two dimensions')
```

We need to remove everything in the `[]` completely.